# Laravel 6 create a JSON from array and store to S3

Tags: json, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I got an array like following

```
data: {
  mobiles: {
   samsung: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Samsung Galaxy A20s",
        launched: "23rd September 2019",
        os: "Android 9 Pie"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Samsung Galaxy A10s",
        launched: "12th August 2019",
        os: "Android 9 Pie"
      },
      {
       ....
      }
  ]
 }
}
```

I want to upload this data to `Amazon S3` bucket as an `.json` file.

PS: I know I can create a json file using `json_encode` and `file_put_contents`, and store to local storage folder first then upload that file to S3, but I want to know if I can upload directly to s3 without create a file in my local. Help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Laravel's [filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem) abstraction does support S3

Comment: I know `Storage::disk('s3')->put('files/mobiles.json', $fileContents);`. If I put `$fileContents=json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` is that gonna work?

Comment: it should. Have you tried it?

Comment: There is no file input, I'm generating json from my database data.

Comment: `put` does not need a file input. It only needs file data and a destination filename

Answer (score 2):

Just pass your array lets say **$data** like so:

```
$fileName = $uuid . '-data.json'; // if you want a unique filename create a uuid
$path = "if_you_want_it_in_folder/$fileName";
Storage::disk('s3')->put($path, json_encode($data));

// Now just save the path so you can access the file later
$myModel->data_key = $path;
$myModel->save();
```